# Do reborrowings and neologisms statistically help the communicative function of the languages or do the cause more confusion?

Tags: syntax, etymology, historical-linguistics, semantics, morphology

Rephrasing do reborrowings and neologisms help or bedim the communications?
I am making the distinction of instantaneous or contemporary communications(especialy for scientific use and social)  and intertemporary communications(especially History). Nonetheless I am interested in both.

For example systemic did not exist as a word in Greek there was no distinction between what was related to a system and what happened as a system. Systematic encompassed both definitions.

The rules of word derivation in the Greek language require nouns ending in -μα to give words from the genitive case συστήματος > συστηματικός, εκτρώματος > εκτρωματικός. A(out of more) special case being διάστημα, which gave διαστημικός, directly from the nominative and not διαστηματικός as one would expect probably for euphony. Chaos giving Chao"t"ic and not Chaoic.

When a language reborrows a word we can't expect the other languages to preserve the rules of the original language σύστημα became system so in English it is perfectly correct to create systemic. We must choose whether to reborrow or not the responsibility is uniquelly ours.

Most dictionaries especially prestigious or older ones do not include the entry in them for neologisms or reborrowings so many people are not familiar with the 
relatively new word and there is no reference to research or scientific(linguistic) consensus what it means. Even reaching consensus is hard because we have problems in the etymology.

Neologisms and Reborrowings can make a distinction in the multiple definitions of a word so we need less context to decide how the word was used. A potential economy in text length and thence simpler syntax.

Statistically/Probabilistically when does the potential distinction help more than the ensuing confusion harms?

Comment: How is this measurable in general? All language change happens because of a perceived need, even if that need is sometimes just to appear cool.

Comment: Confusion may be a linguistic goal, e,g, to avoid existing expectations, or let a term be defined by usage. There's no clear distinction. Yet, many loans are just not very confusing. *systemic*/*systematic* is not confusing, in my humble opinion, because *-matic* carries a notion of activity, derived from *auto-matic* (even if, as I guess, etymologically incorrect). The premises of your question, the Greek derivation rules, suffers the same problem as you are asking about. So the Q is kind of a tautology. Yes, reinterpretation complicates interpretation.

Comment: @vectory the Greek derivation rules are not a premise of my question. My question is not inferred and does not follow the rules in any way. They are not the basis of my question. The basis is communication not grammar. The derivation rules only illustrate the question. They are an example to help people understand. Loans are not at all confusing the problem is counter-loans. The distinction Systemic/Systematic is not confusing because all dictionaries contain both entries(even Oxford and Cambridge). English is a much younger language and changes rapidly ...ctd

Comment: @vectory A person born and raised today or even 100 years ago would have a very hard time communicating usin Old English. A Modern Greek would have a much easier time with Koine Greek. -matic does not derive from auto-matic and does not carry a notion of activity but rather thought.  αὐτός and μέμαα or μέμονα. What do the Greek derivation rules suffer from and how does my question suffer from the same problem? How can the question be a tautology?

Comment: You are assuming that languages are rigid and become confused only by reinterpreation. This is apparent from your explanation and example using Ancient Greek as a basis, as the gold standard. However, that's eluding the truth. Ancient Greek was prone to folk etymology, too, and to forgetting its roots, to simplify and extend. At that *systema*/*histema* might be no exception, or the exception that proofs the rule, but that's besides the point. Or exactly on point, if the question whether there are few easy rules that everyone should know, and how much--many more difficult rules--is too much

Comment: Why am I assuming that languages are rigid, how so? Where is your premise based on and which are the evidences in my comment? Ancient Greek is not the gold standart it is just that it mantains most rules and vocabularry intact even through its long history. I am also a third-Greek a third-Brazilian and a third- Italian with three nationalities and Portuguese and Greek as my mother languages and only CPE A+(Pass with Distinction) since age 14 and much less knowledge of Italian,Spanish and French(My mom having 2 nationalities by birth 3 currently still speaks portuguese with me) ...ctd

Comment: @vectory I speak Greek with my Father and my younger siblings. I grew up in Greece and most of my education was in Greece. Linguistically I am equally adept in Greek,English and Portuguese but I am much more familiar with Greek due to social interaction. That is why I gave an example from Modern Greek(not Ancient(Attic the classic one)  Doric Ionic Koine(Hellenistic the latter one) or Katharevousa  I just could not think of an example of a counterloan in English going against some rule in the formation of the words. Furthermore languages are only a tool for communication. Its users are the ctd

Comment: @vectory Its users are the ones who may potentially get confused not the language itself. As for systema the words are συν and ἵστημι *stísteh₂- < *steh₂- cognates Latin sto and German stehen. I am not advocating worshiping the roots. And certainly not for historical, religious or nationalistic reasons. I am trying to be economical, functional, telological. Language is a tool mainly for communicating, you won't use a hammer to screw, do reborrowings and neologisms do more harm than good? That is my pure(with no impurities,mixtures) question. Not neologisms themselves but rather communication.

Comment: "*it mantains most rules and vocabularry intact even through its long history.*", "*pure(with no impurities,mixtures)*", you are aware that the early phases are arguably the most important for the formation of the language, but pretty much in the dark. There's the fallacy in your assumption. There's no *dillution* that could impair its purity, because it was never "pure".

Comment: "*it mantains most rules and vocabularry intact even through its long history.*", "*pure(with no impurities,mixtures)*", you are aware that the early phases are arguably the most important for the formation of the language, but pretty much in the dark. There's the fallacy in your assumption. There's no *dillution* that could impair its purity, because it was never "pure".

Comment: And while that doesn't solve your question if you assume that Greek was table at some point for a long but limited time and with its extend limited mainly to written speech, its nevertheless inviting to inspect the notion a little closer pertaining to your example. Systema, συν + ἵστημι, is a perplexing derivation, if *histemi* went \*stistheti > \*sistheti > *hist- ... which is still perplexing because *-m* might rather reflect \*stemn-. The point is that a reinterpretation of the reduplicated stem as prefix seems more likely than a bona-fide composition with a prefix.

Comment: I see now that a) Proto-Indo-European \*stísteh₂ti is reconstructed with 1st person \*stísteh₂mi, but I don't know why. I'm aware that *-mai* at least is a frequent Greek verb morpheme, but again, I don't know how it's derived. In contrast, we see a noun \**stéh₂mn̥, with the frequent morpheme \*-mn̥ that relates to a whole slew of other morphemes alternating in the ablaut, and also to \*-h₃onh₂- and variations denoting "burden, authority", which does incidentally fit *the system*. We also see that *systematic* is derived through σῠνῐ́στημῐ +‎ -μᾰ (-ma) (\*-mn̥).

Comment: b) σῠνῐ́στημῐ (sunistemi) might be a backformation after interpretation of *σύστημα (sústēma) as containing σύν (sún). It should be hard to decide which way it went, precisely because potential loans into cognate languages (and the archaism that I alleged) could sufficiently complicate the issue c) Because of *stem*, German *Stamm* (trunk, tribe, origin, backbone) I am keen to see *systemic* as "from the stem/core" d) The derivation of σύν (reflected in En. *sy-, syn, sym*) is not clear at all. So: That's why I say your premises of "rules of word derivation in the Greek language" is faulty.

Comment: I should say "might be".

Comment: @vectory My pure question not my pure language.  I am not saying any foreign influences are evil. When I said with no impurities I meant communication in itself as the only goal, pursued in its own right to the exclusion of all others. My question is; Do reborrowings and neologisms do more harm than good(to communication)? Just that I am not one to advocate to "purify" the language. I thought you understood.

Comment: @vectory Let us please stop discussing the rules of derivation in the Greek language. They are not important in my question. I gave just an example if you want me to I can remove it and just give me an English counterloan not contained in Oxford and Cambridge that goes against the rules of formation. Please understand(respect) my question and don't jump into assumptions e.g that I am a purist. My question is not about derivation but rather counterloans and neologisms. If they do more harm than good! I know what I am asking if you can't understand it please ask me directlly what seems vague!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that languages are constantly going through an enormous and surprisingly rapid process of natural selection. The whole point of language is to communicate, and if something gets in the way of that, it'll quickly be replaced, worked around, or eliminated.

So if a word is borrowed, or reborrowed, or created, it's because *the speakers of the language found it useful*. It enhances their communication in some way: or else it'll quickly disappear from the language.

For a concrete example, nothing's stopping me from borrowing Swahili *isimu* to replace English "linguistics". I could start calling myself a *mwanaisimu*, search for *isimu* at the library, petition to rename this StackExchange site. But if I did, I'm quite confident it wouldn't catch on, and it would just confuse everyone I talked to. If I wanted to communicate with English-speakers in a productive way, I'd have to call it "linguistics" instead.

So when a new term *does* catch on, it's because people have found it helpful. Its existence makes communication easier or clearer in some way. Even though "systemic" and "systematic" both derive in some way from Greek *συστήμα(τ)* with the suffix *-ικός*, they've become separate words in English because English-speakers find that distinction helpful. If Greek-speakers also find it useful enough to justify separate words, we're likely to see *συστημικός* or the like alongside *συστηματικός*. Only time will tell.

P.S. As Colin Fine mentions in the comments, culture can also be a totally valid reason for a word to be useful: the utility of *yeet* in English comes from popular/internet/meme culture. But even here, it's enhancing communication in some way: when someone finishes a Tumblr post with "yeet", they're communicating a meaning you couldn't quite get without that word. In a hundred years, "yeet" might still be around, or it might have died out; it all depends if people keep finding it useful or not.

Comment: Actually the reason of counterloans(my only problem) can very well be trade etc. If the U.S call some banks systemic Greece is self-pressured to call the same type of banks systemic. Economists are not Linguists they have only superficially studied the derivation rules in 7-10 Grade and most good ones study in U.S or U.K most professors in Greek universities have studied in the U.S or U.K. Most people find some words extremely strange. We have no dictionaries. no consensus and problems in etymology. The redeeming quality is potential economy in language.

Comment: Systemic will not fade away because most Greeks are incommoded. Economists, Engineers, Mathematicians, Physicists, Chemists will still use it. Their pool is constantly refilled.

Comment: "it's *because the speakers of the language found it useful*." -- That's drastically oversimplifying the issue. You paint it as an ideal, but utility is an optimum and therefore a matter of many factors that may stand at odds; confounding factors may play a role. Its paradox to call e.g. ignorance--one potential factor of the equation--or misuse generally "useful". I don't think its helpful if a thief calls *my wallet* suddenly *their wallet*, or if an unwelcome issue is swept under the rug by use of nebulous euphemism. In short, I'd say you didn't answer the question, but I can't blame you.

Comment: As far as the example is concerned, we can assume that translating *systemic* to Greek wouldn't have been any easier, without altering the meaning. That's the actual question here, wouldn't it have been easier? And what does it actually mean, anyway (as OP and myself to be honest have problems interpreting it; The dictionary definition surprised me). Following this answer, the detriment of the loan is negligible and its systemic that a linguist would think, you just need to know the words proper derivation, or, if lacking knowledge of Germanic, accept the word as is. Which would be agonizing.

Comment: @vectory Draconis at least understood my question. The question is not specifically about systemic, or the Greek language. But rather whether counteloans and neologisms do more harm than good.

Comment: @Draconis Systemic will not fade away because most Greeks are incommoded. Economists, Engineers, Mathematicians, Physicists, Chemists will still use it. Their pool is constantly refilled. And there are countless examples just like systemic. Counterloans are often scientific pseudo-lingo. Do you still abide by your opinion that any change made to a language does more good than harm?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Good for the speakers of the language, for the purpose of communicating? I absolutely do. That's why changes happen. Good overall? Well, that's more subjective.

Comment: @Draconis changes do not happen just telologically. It can very well be the trade. Systemic will not fade away because most Greeks are incommoded. Economists, Engineers, Mathematicians, Physicists, Chemists will still use it. Their pool is constantly refilled. Because the best one study in the U.S and U.K. While everyone else is estranged. We have no dictionaries. no consensus and problems in etymology. The only redeeming quality is potential economy in language. Because of potentially less context needs. You can read my comments to vectory about Oxford, Cambridge dictionaries and the history

Comment: @Draconis History of the English language. English is the current lingua franca for academia, trade, e.t.c. That is why you will not face the same potential problem.

Comment: @Draconis Do you have any idea? Any suggestion?